# Aplicação desenvolvida no Delphi XE8 fecha na execução

Tags: android, delphi

A aplicação foi desenvolvida para a versão **4.4.2** do *Android*, e quando eu abro essa app no **Android 6.0**, ele abre mas fecha logo em seguida.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Já tentou rodar seu app em um aparelho com a versão 4.4.2 ?

Comment: sim, na 4.4.2 funciona perfeitamente! Até na versão 5 funcionou.. mas na 6.0 ele agarrou!

Comment: Tens uma licença do Delphi ou está usando ele crackeado ?

Comment: ele tá licenciado...

Answer (score 2):

Poder ser pela versão do Android, você precisa baixar o HotFix que a embarcadero lançou , assim os aplicativos vão funcionar em Android's superiores a 5.0.

http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110 entre com usuário e senha que foram usados para registrar a licença e baixe ele.

Comment: estou usando xe8.. aqui fala que é para xe7..

Comment: O aplicativo funciona na versão 4.4.2 mas ao executar o mesmo na versão 6.0 ele fecha, você está com o SDK Tools atualizado com a última versão. Se eu não me engano a última versão é a 25.2.5

Comment: @ThiagoAvila, realmente o XE8 já tem todos os hotfixes instalado, era para funcionar, se não funcionar atualizando o SDK Tools tens que verificar se o dispositivo é compatível com RADStudio, de uma olhada nesse link:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development

Comment: conferi aqui e meu android tools estava desatualizado.. mas estou atualizando pra 25.2.5!

Comment: atualizei, fiz novo aplicativo e continua sem rodar..

Comment: @ThiagoAvila, acesse o link que eu passei no comentário anterior, tente verificar se o dispositivo é compatível.

Comment: @ThiagoAvila, o que pode está acontecendo é está ocorrendo um problema quando abre aplicação no smartphone com Android 6.0 e ele fecha, pois o XE7 mostra exceções só até o android 5.0, para mostrar exceções para o smartphone 6.0 tem que desenvolver no Seatle. Da uma conferida nesse link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page